# CakePHP 2.x - Disable translation behavior on specific controller's action

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, locale, cakephp-2.6

I would like to know whether there is a way to disable the translation behavior for certain controller's action.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example:**

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
 $this->Category->Behaviors->unload('Translate');
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#using-behaviors